# Encode in scraping data with Python

Tags: python, html-encode

I want to scrape the content of websites with Python. Just like this:

```
Apple’s stock continued to dominate the news over the weekend, with Barron’s placing it on the top of its favorite 2013 stock list.
```

But print them with error result:

```
Apple âs stock continued to dominate the news over the weekend, with Barronâs placing it on the top of its favorite 2013 stock list.
```

The symbol "’" can't be shown, here is my code:

```
    #-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import sys
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
    import urllib
    from lxml import *
    import urllib
    import lxml.html as HTML

    url = "http://www.forbes.com/sites/panosmourdoukoutas/2012/12/09/apple-tops-barrons- 10-favorite-stocks-for-2013/?partner=yahootix"
    sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmlSource = sock.read()
    sock.close()

    root = HTML.document_fromstring(htmlSource)
    contents = ' '.join([x.strip() for x in root.xpath("//div[@class='body']/descendant::text()")])

    print contents

    f = open('C:/Users/yinyao/Desktop/Python Code/data.txt','w')
    f.write(contents)
    f.close()
```

However, after setting, the function of printf is not useful. Why? And what should I do?
I'm using Windows, and the default encoding approach is gbk.

Comment: Can you post the code that is doing the scraping?

Comment: How are you printing the statement? Please post the exact command you executed to print the statement. There is no printf function in python, is there?

Comment: Try [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure that you know [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Second, **always** use unicode internally. Decode early, encode late: when you scrap a website, decode it to unicode and process it as unicode internally in your script. Otherwise your code will crash at random points, for example because it encountered an unexpected character in a comment in some webpage in Chinese. Only when you pass it later somewhere (e.g., to some writeable stream) you should encode it ("utf-8" preferably)

Third, use [BeautifulSoup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Thanks! But I don't know when and how to decode the website data to unicode.I have reedited my question and shown my codes, can you give me more suggestions about my codes?

Comment: First, format your question *properly* http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks , so the code is readable. Second, BautifulSoup will handle unicode for you

Comment: Thanks! BeautifulSoup is useful,but I have fixed it by decoding the htmlSource to unicode.